# Python, Pick numbers, with a given total sum

Tags: python, list

`[[-1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1], [-2, 6, 4]]`
For example I have this two dimensional array, and I need to pick the combination of numbers (one from each sublist) that in total give some number, let's say -1, so the right numbers will be -1 from the first, 2 from the second and -2 from the third. What is the fastest and easiest way to do it?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you also demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the text based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. If you need a nudge getting started check out `itertools.product()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use itertools.product but that's not the fastest (it is simple brute force over all possible combinations):

```
from itertools import product

numbers = [[-1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1], [-2, 6, 4]]

print(*(p for p in product(*numbers) if sum(p) == -1))
# (-1, 2, -2) 

print(*(p for p in product(*numbers) if sum(p) == 7))
# (-1, 4, 4) (-1, 2, 6) (2, 1, 4)
```

Getting something faster will require diving into [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) and [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) which will no longer be the simplest way (there's always a trade off)